Any FEM book recommendations that focus on stability and proofs on error bounds?
Everything from descrete stability proofs for steady state and time dependent problems. energy stability, stability of mixed methods, nonlinear problems, vector valued problems in fluid/structural/EM, use of mixed FEMs/CG/DG, LBM and lax milligram for stability, descrete stability for different time discritizaition schemes...

Since nobody has replied, don't the books by Brenner and Scott or the five or six series by Oden and Carey have what you want?

I would suggest the books below:

Susanne C. Brenner , L. Ridgway Scott - The Mathematical Theory of
Finite Element Methods
Daniele Boffi , Franco Brezzi , Michel Fortin - Mixed Finite Element Methods and Applications
Elman, H Silvester, D Wathen, A - Finite Elements and Fast Iterative Solvers
Daniele Antonio Di Pietro , Alexandre Ern - Mathematical Aspects of Discontinuous Galerkin Methods
Béatrice Rivière - Discontinuous Galerkin Methods for Solving Elliptic and Parabolic Equations: Theory and Implementation
Jan S. Hesthaven , Tim Warburton - Nodal Discontinuous Galerkin Methods: Algorithms, Analysis, and Applications
Peter Wriggers - Nonlinear Finite Element Methods

These should cover most of the asker's requests, if anyone has suggestions I am happy to evaluate and add to the list.

Great list. I would also add Wriggers as a reference specifically on nonlinear problems.

Nonlinear Finite Elements by Wriggers, definitely a great suggestion. Thank you! :)
